# setState is not setting state of an variable declared as empty array in class component of ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a problem of a state that is not being updated when I call the local storage get item in `componentdidmount()` function of the class component.

Here the state `myAddress` is assigned to get the JSON data stored in localStorage and then setting itself as `setState` but instead of this it is showing `undefined` in console log. We can add the data for the first time only when we refresh the page it throws the `[Object, Object]` error.

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faAdd, faBackward, faDeleteLeft, faHandDots, faKeyboard, faLocation, faLocationArrow, faLocationDot, faPlusCircle, faRecycle, faRemove, faRemoveFormat, faTrash, faTrashCan, faUserEdit } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import swal from 'sweetalert';



export default class Address extends Component {
 constructor(props){
     super(props);
  
 this.state = {
    addNewAdd: false,
    myAddress:[],
    editAddress: false,
    fullName: '', 
    mobileNumber: '',
    pinCode: '',
    houseNo: '',
    areaVill: '',
    landMark: '',
    townCity: '',
    state: '',
    default: false,
    addressType: '',
    uniqueID: ''
    };        
}



AddNewAddress = () => this.setState({addNewAdd:true});

saveAddress = () => {
    if(this.state.fullName === "" || this.state.mobileNumber === "" || this.state.pinCode === "" || this.state.houseNo === "" || this.state.areaVill === "" || this.state.landMark === "" || this.state.townCity === "" || this.state.state === "" || this.state.addressType === ""){
           swal("Empty Values", "All Fields are empty, Fill to proceed","error");
    }
    else{
        const newData = [{
            fullName : this.state.fullName,
            mobileNumber: this.state.mobileNumber,
            pinCode: this.state.pinCode,
            houseNo: this.state.houseNo,
            areaVill: this.state.areaVill,
            landMark: this.state.landMark,
            townCity: this.state.townCity,
            state: this.state.state,
            default: this.state.default,
            addressType: this.state.addressType
        }]
        if(this.state.editAddress === false){
            let jsonData;
            jsonData = JSON.stringify(newData);
            this.setState({myAddress : [...this.state.myAddress, jsonData]});
            swal("Address Saved", "Your Address has been saved !", "success");
            this.setState = {
                fullName: '', 
                mobileNumber: '',
                pinCode: '',
                houseNo: '',
                areaVill: '',
                landMark: '',
                townCity: '',
                state: '',
                default: false,
                addressType: '',
                addNewAdd: false
                };
        }
        else{
            const newArrayData = this.state.myAddress.filter((data) =>  data.uniqueId !== this.state.uniqueID);
            alert(JSON.stringify(newArrayData));
            newArrayData = JSON.stringify(newArrayData);
            swal("Address Saved", "Your Edit in Address has been saved !", "success");
            this.setState({addNewAdd: false});
        }
  }
}

exitAddressForm = () =>{
    this.setState({addNewAdd: false});
    this.setState({
        fullName: '', 
        mobileNumber: '',
        pinCode: '',
        houseNo: '',
        areaVill: '',
        landMark: '',
        townCity: '',
        state: '',
        default: false,
        addressType: '',
        editAddress:false
        });
}

editSavedAddress = (uniqueId) =>{
    this.setState({addNewAdd: true})
    let addressData, newJsonData;
    const addressEs = localStorage.getItem("myAddress");
    if(addressEs){
        addressData = JSON.parse(addressEs);
        newJsonData = addressData.filter((data) =>  data.uniqueId === uniqueId);
        newJsonData.map((data, index) =>{
             this.setState({
                editAddress:true,
                fullName: data.fullName, 
                mobileNumber: data.mobileNumber,
                pinCode: data.pinCode,
                houseNo: data.houseNo,
                areaVill: data.areaVill,
                landMark: data.landMark,
                townCity: data.townCity,
                state: data.state,
                default: data.default,
                addressType: data.addressType,
                uniqueID: data.uniqueId
        });
    });
  }
} 

componentDidMount(){
    const addressEs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myAddress")) || [];
    console.log("Length :  " + Object.keys(addressEs).length);
    if(Object.keys(addressEs).length > 0){
        this.setState({myAddress: addressEs});
    }
}


componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log("state " + this.state.myAddress); 
        localStorage.setItem("myAddress", this.state.myAddress);
}

render() {      
    return (
        <>
        <div className='container mx-auto w-[60%]'>
        <div className='w-full lg:flex md:flex mt-5'>
            <div className='drop-shadow-lg lg:w-[80%] md:w-[80%] m-4 sm:w-full'>
                <div className='bg-white p-3 rounded-t-md text-lg'>Address</div>
                { Object.keys(this.state.myAddress).length > 0 & ! this.state.addNewAdd ? 
                this.state.myAddress.map((data, index) => (
                    <><div key={index} className="mt-2 text-left bg-white rounded-lg font-sans flex flex-wrap">
                        <div className='bg-green-200 w-[25%] text-center p-2 text-blue-600 hover:text-green-700 hover:transition hover:delay-100'>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLocationDot} size='8x' />
                        </div>
                        <div className='p-4 w-[60%]'>
                        <b>{data.fullName}</b><br/>
                        {data.houseNo}<br/>
                        {data.areaVill},&nbsp; 
                        {data.landMark},&nbsp;
                        {data.townCity}<br/>
                        <b>Pin Code</b> {data.pinCode}&nbsp;, {data.state}<br/>
                        <b>India</b> , Phone Number : {data.mobileNumber} 
                        </div>
                        <div className='bg-white w-[15%] p-2 grid grid-rows-3 text-center mx-auto border-l-2 border-dotted'>
                            <div className='h-[33%]'>
                                <button onClick={() => this.editSavedAddress(data.uniqueId)} className='p-1 text-gray-300 hover:text-gray-800'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserEdit} size='2x'/></button>
                            </div>
                            <div className='h-[33%]'>
                                <button className='mt-2 -ml-2 text-gray-300 hover:text-gray-800'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} size='2x'/></button>
                            </div>   
                            { data.default ? <><div className='h-[33%] p-1 mt-1 -ml-2'>
                                <button className='text-gray-300 hover:text-gray-800'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDeleteLeft} size='2x'/></button>
                            </div></> :                         
                            <div className='h-[33%] p-1 mt-1 -ml-2'>
                                <button className='text-gray-300 hover:text-gray-800'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faKeyboard} size='2x'/></button>
                            </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div></>
                ))
                :null
                } 

                {this.state.addNewAdd ? <>
                        <div className='bg-gray-100 p-4 w-full text-left'>
                            Full Name <br/>
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.fullName} onChange={(e) => this.setState({fullName: e.target.value})} className='mr-2 mt-2 mb-2 p-1 border-[1px] border-gray-500 rounded-md w-full'/><br/>
                           Mobile Number<br/>
                        <input type="number" value={this.state.mobileNumber} onChange={(e) => this.setState({mobileNumber: e.target.value})} className='mr-2 mt-2 mb-2 p-1 border-[1px] border-gray-500 rounded-md w-full'/><br/>
                         Pin Code<br/>
                        <input type="number" value={this.state.pinCode} onChange={(e) => this.setState({pinCode: e.target.value})} className='mr-2 mt-2 mb-2 p-1 border-[1px] border-gray-500 rounded-md w-full'/><br/>
                        Flat, House no., Building, Company, Apartment<br/>
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.houseNo} onChange={(e) => this.setState({houseNo: e.target.value})} className='mr-2 mt-2 mb-2 p-1 border-[1px] border-gray-500 rounded-md w-full'/><br/>
                        Area, Street, Sector, Village<br/>
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.areaVill} onChange={(e) => this.setState({areaVill: e.target.value})} className='mr-2 mt-2 mb-2 p-1 border-[1px] border-gray-500 rounded-md w-full'/><br/>
                        Landmark<br/>
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.landMark} onChange={(e) => this.setState({landMark: e.target.value})} className='mr-2 mt-2 mb-2 p-1 border-[1px] border-gray-500 rounded-md w-full' placeholder='Eg Near Sec 15 Main Market'/><br/>   
                        <div className='flex'>
                        <div className='w-[50%]'>Town/City
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.townCity} onChange={(e) => this.setState({townCity: e.target.value})} className='mr-2 mt-2 mb-2 p-1 border-[1px] border-gray-500 rounded-md w-[80%]' placeholder=''/>
                        </div>
                        <div className='w-[50%]'>State<br/>
                          <select name="state" id="state" value={this.state.state} className="p-1 bg-gray-200 rounded-lg mt-1 h-10 w-[100%]"  onChange={(e) => this.setState({state: e.target.value})}>
                               <option value="0">Choose</option>
                                <option value="Andhra Pradesh">Andhra Pradesh</option>
                                <option value="Andaman and Nicobar Islands">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
                                <option value="Arunachal Pradesh">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
                                <option value="Assam">Assam</option>
                                <option value="Bihar">Bihar</option>
                                <option value="Chandigarh">Chandigarh</option>
                                <option value="Chhattisgarh">Chhattisgarh</option>
                                <option value="Dadar and Nagar Haveli">Dadar and Nagar Haveli</option>
                                <option value="Daman and Diu">Daman and Diu</option>
                                <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                                <option value="Lakshadweep">Lakshadweep</option>
                                <option value="Puducherry">Puducherry</option>
                                <option value="Goa">Goa</option>
                                <option value="Gujarat">Gujarat</option>
                                <option value="Haryana">Haryana</option>
                                <option value="Himachal Pradesh">Himachal Pradesh</option>
                                <option value="Jammu and Kashmir">Jammu and Kashmir</option>
                                <option value="Jharkhand">Jharkhand</option>
                                <option value="Karnataka">Karnataka</option>
                                <option value="Kerala">Kerala</option>
                                <option value="Madhya Pradesh">Madhya Pradesh</option>
                                <option value="Maharashtra">Maharashtra</option>
                                <option value="Manipur">Manipur</option>
                                <option value="Meghalaya">Meghalaya</option>
                                <option value="Mizoram">Mizoram</option>
                                <option value="Nagaland">Nagaland</option>
                                <option value="Odisha">Odisha</option>
                                <option value="Punjab">Punjab</option>
                                <option value="Rajasthan">Rajasthan</option>
                                <option value="Sikkim">Sikkim</option>
                                <option value="Tamil Nadu">Tamil Nadu</option>
                                <option value="Telangana">Telangana</option>
                                <option value="Tripura">Tripura</option>
                                <option value="Uttar Pradesh">Uttar Pradesh</option>
                                <option value="Uttarakhand">Uttarakhand</option>
                                <option value="West Bengal">West Bengal</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="checkbox" value={this.state.default} className='accent-pink-500 w-4 h-4' checked={this.state.default}  onChange={(e) => this.state.default ? this.setState({default: false}) : this.setState({default: true})}/> &nbsp;Make this address default <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <h2><b>Add Delivery Instructions</b></h2>
                        Preferences are used to plan your delivery. However, shipments can sometimes arrive early or later than planned.
                        <br/>
                        <b>Address Type</b>
                         <select name="state" id="state" value={this.state.addressType} className="p-1 bg-gray-200 rounded-lg mt-1 h-10 w-[100%]" onChange={(e) => this.setState({addressType: e.target.value})}>
                                <option value="0">Choose</option>
                                <option value="Home">Home</option>
                                <option value="office">Office or Commercial</option>
                         </select>
                         <div>
                             <button className='mt-4 border-2 bg-yellow-500 rounded-lg px-3 py-1 text-white hover:bg-gray-800 hover:transition hover:delay-100 active:transform' onClick={this.saveAddress}>Save</button>
                             <button className='mt-4 ml-4 border-2 bg-orange-600 rounded-lg px-3 py-1 text-white hover:bg-gray-800 hover:transition hover:delay-100 active:transform'>Save & Back</button>
                             <button className='mt-4 ml-4 border-2 bg-blue-500 rounded-lg px-3 py-1 text-white hover:bg-gray-800 hover:transition hover:delay-100  active:transform'>Clear</button>
                         </div>       
                        </div> 
                </>:null}
            </div>
            <div className='drop-shadow-lg lg:w-[20%] md:w-[20%] m-4 sm:w-full'>
                { ! this.state.addNewAdd ?
                <button onClick={this.AddNewAddress}>
                <div className='bg-orange-600 text-white p-4 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md hover:bg-white hover:text-gray-800 hover:transition hover:delay-100 w-[100%]'>
                    <div><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusCircle} size='4x' /></div>
                    <div className='mt-4'>Add New Address</div>
                </div>
                </button>
                :
                <button onClick={this.exitAddressForm}>
                <div className='bg-indigo-800 text-white p-4 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md hover:bg-white hover:text-gray-800 hover:transition hover:delay-100 w-[100%]'>
                    <div><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBackward} size='4x' /></div>
                    <div className='mt-4'>Exit Address Form</div>
                </div>
                </button>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )
   }
}
```

Comment: "but instead of this it is showing undefined in console log" - where exactly is this log in the code snippet? `componentDidUpdate` isn't JSON stringifying the `this.state.myAddress` array. Also, in `saveAddress` function you are mutating the `this.setState` value.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese Here I am using the `componentDidUpdate` to save the data to local storage whenever there is a change in the state of `myAddress`.... A matter of fact is that data is being stored but I am not able to fetch it..as it is showing `[Object Object]` in console.

Comment: You are storing it in localStorage as an object. ‍♂️ Are you saying that `this.state.myAddress` is updated, and then persisted to localStorage... and then later you reload the app and fetch it from localStorage and now it's an object? It is an object though, so I don't think the localStorage is much a part of this issue. Where is it becoming an issue? When you are trying to render it? It appears to be an array, so mapping it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,  I got the answer... There was a mistake in the syntax of setState...

```
this.setState = {
            fullName: '', 
            mobileNumber: '',
            pinCode: '',
            houseNo: '',
            areaVill: '',
            landMark: '',
            townCity: '',
            state: '',
            default: false,
            addressType: '',
            addNewAdd: false
            };
```

above code need to be written as follows-

```
this.setState({
            fullName: '', 
            mobileNumber: '',
            pinCode: '',
            houseNo: '',
            areaVill: '',
            landMark: '',
            townCity: '',
            state: '',
            default: false,
            addressType: '',
            addNewAdd: false
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

**setState** takes a **callback** function which is called when a state is to be changed :

Corresponding syntax of setState in class component:

```
The callback inside setState returns a new state .
this.setState(()=>{ 
    return { ...this.state,
            fullName: '', 
            mobileNumber: '',
            pinCode: '',
            houseNo: '',
            areaVill: '',
            landMark: '',
            townCity: '',
            state: '',
            default: false,
            addressType: '',
            addNewAdd: false
    })
```

```
Here , we are directly returning a new object as a state .
this.setState({
            fullName: '', 
            mobileNumber: '',
            pinCode: '',
            houseNo: '',
            areaVill: '',
            landMark: '',
            townCity: '',
            state: '',
            default: false,
            addressType: '',
            addNewAdd: false
    })
```